# Serial Port Hangs

Tags: macos, unix, serial-port, posix, ftdi

I have a usb to serial FTDI adaptor connected to my mac. I am able to use the command:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC
```

This opens a serial terminal for the port and everything works fine. But when I try to send characters to the serial port via the command:

```
root# echo 'a' > /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC
```

the command hangs and nothing is ever sent. A similar thing happens when I try to connect to it in a c program. The program hangs trying to open the serial port:

```
int fd = open("/dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
```

When I run stty on the port it prints:

```
root# stty -f  /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo
iflags: -icrnl -ixon -ixany -imaxbel -brkint
oflags: -opost -onlcr -oxtabs
cflags: cs8 -parenb
```

which looks correct. Does anybody have an ideas as to why these commands hang and never send when connecting to the serial port yet screen works just fine? Any help will be appreciated.

Update: The results of getting info from stty

```
bash-3.2# stty -a -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC
speed 9600 baud; 0 rows; 0 columns;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoke -echonl
-echoctl -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin
-nokerninfo -extproc
iflags: -istrip -icrnl -inlcr -igncr -ixon -ixoff -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-ignbrk -brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: -opost -onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
-dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: *"Hang"* seems to be your favorite word that you overuse. *"The program hangs trying to open the serial port"* - that, if accurate, could indicate a serious kernel issue; the kernel should never hang.  There's a good chance you are not correctly describing the problem.   How do you determine that *"nothing is ever sent'*?  One end of this USB-serial link is your Mac; what is at the other end?

Comment: The other end is connected to a logic analyzer where I have verified no state change on the tx line. The issue is one if software. To clarify I use the word hang to describe the behavior or a command being executed but never returning.

Comment: Could you please try `stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC clocal`? If it does not help could you please show output of `stty -a -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC` both before and during the terminal is opened in `screen`?

Comment: I clocal command did not seem to fix anything. Running stty -a durring the screen results in a resorce bussy message and running the comand afterwards  yells:`bash-3.2# stty -a -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC
speed 9600 baud; 0 rows; 0 columns;` Followed by a listing of all the available flags for the device which unfortunately are to long to fit in a comment.Thanks for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: OK, thanks. **a)** Could you please open the serial port device in `screen` and then `kill -9` the `screen` process and then run `stty -a -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A601L9OC`. **b)** Other possibility is to try `open()` with `O_NONBLOCK` option. Be aware of the behaviour that `read()` will immediately return `EAGAIN` when there will be no data to read.

Comment: I had a similar problem, writing a cross-platform app which would "hang" reading the port on Macosx but not on Linux machines using the same code. Furthermore if you tried to access the port again, e.g. using stty, it would run at 100% CPU, high I/O until a hard-reboot! Nothing I know of could kill the process (including sudo kill -9, nor the mac shutdown - it would also hang forever). I also could not prevent it via stty configuration. The solution (as below) was to use cu not tty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the device `/dev/cu.usbserial-A601L9OC` instead, and set the speed to 9600 baud also. Here's an example from [Magnus' macrumor post](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-development-darwin/172442-problem-open-dev-tty-usbserial.html#post929826):

```
strcpy(bsdPath, "/dev/cu.usbserial-A601L9OC");
fileDescriptor = open(bsdPath, O_RDWR);
if (-1 == fileDescriptor)
{
return EX_IOERR;
}

struct termios theTermios;
memset(&theTermios, 0, sizeof(struct termios));
cfmakeraw(&theTermios);
cfsetspeed(&theTermios, 9600);
theTermios.c_cflag = CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ and ignore modem control lines
theTermios.c_cflag |= CS8;
theTermios.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
theTermios.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;     // 1 sec timeout
int ret = ioctl(fileDescriptor, TIOCSETA, &theTermios);

ret = read(fileDescriptor, &c, 1);
```

Comment: [This page](http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-tty.html) discusses the difference between `cu.*` and `tty.*`

Comment: Thank you @grebneke, good to know what's the difference, I quoted: `The technical difference is that /dev/tty.* devices will wait (or listen) for DCD (data-carrier-detect), eg, someone calling in, before responding. /dev/cu.* devices do not assert DCD, so they will always connect (respond or succeed) immediately.`

Comment: Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Use O_NONBLOCK otherwise the open waits for Carrier Detect.